# Ruby - How to return matched Regexp value

Tags: regex, ruby

I am playing around with some Regular expresion macthers in ruby,
Currently I am returning the value `true` in my code.

```
pattern = Regexp.union(['+', '-']) #=> /\+|\-/
['foo', '+', 'bar'].any?(pattern) #=> true
```

How would I go about returning the string `'+'` from this?

Comment: Use `.grep` instead of `any?`?

Comment: @TheMayerof to find these methods, open the docs for [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html) and search for "pattern".

Comment: If you're just looking for *something* that matches, or even explicitly *the first* thing that matches, I'd use `['foo', '+', 'bar'].find { |x| x.match?(pattern) }`. Using `grep` will return an `Array` of **all** the elements that matched. Which might be what you want, but it's not what you asked us for. (`'+'` is a string; `['+']` is an array that contains one string.)

Comment: If performance is an issue, you can also trick `grep` into returning early via `[...].enum_for(:grep, pattern).first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
pattern = Regexp.union(['+', '-']) #=> /\+|\-/
```

using operator

```
['foo', '+', 'bar'].select{ |e| e =~ pattern }
=>["+"]
```

using match? method

```
['foo', '+', 'bar'].select{ |e| e.match?(pattern) 
=>["+"]
```

using String#[]

```
['foo', '+', 'bar'].select{ |e| e[pattern] }
=>["+"]
```